# if-else optimization & gotchas?

Tags: java, optimization, if-statement

I have two simple snippets of code below.Snippet 1 do not have else condition.Logically both snippets serve the same purpose.

I would like to know if there are any gotchas or any optimization improvements if I am to choose between the two snippets in my program ?

**Snippet 1**

```
public boolean isOauthTokenValid(long oauthExpiryTimestamp){

    if (oauthExpiryTimestamp >= System.currentTimeMillis()){
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

**Snippet 2**

```
public boolean isOauthTokenValid(long oauthExpiryTimestamp){

    if (oauthExpiryTimestamp >= System.currentTimeMillis()){
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Will this gives optimization in the bytecode level ?

Comment: will it give any performance improvement in the bytecode level ? or just increase readability

Comment: `if (…) return true else return false;` makes no sense whatsoever. Just do `return …;`.

Comment: beware premature optimization -

Comment: beware invoking the term "premature optimization" to discourage people from thinking about how things actually work

Comment: There is no such thing as "performance improvement at the bytecode level", unless you are deliberately shutting off JVM optimizations---and in that case you clearly do not care about performance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Dispense with the `if` altogether.  You can directly use the result of the comparison:

```
return (oauthExpiryTimestamp >= System.currentTimeMillis());
```

Comment: Thank you! Not using this idiom is one of my biggest pet peeves when it comes to programming style.

Answer (score 3):

Even simpler:

```
return oauthExpiryTimestamp >= System.currentTimeMillis();
```

In this way, you can avoid the need to use a conditional in your code. But anyway, the performance gain will be negligible.

Why this works? because if the boolean expression in the condition is `true` you're returning `true` and if it's `false` you're returning `false` - so it's enough to return the value of the boolean expression.

Comment: @TitoCheriachan "maybe". It depends on the static compiler, and anyway the JIT compiler might optimize it to the same code at runtime. What's important here is that both versions are _semantically_ equivalent, and the fact that the performance difference obtained for using either one is negligible. It's more important to write code that's easy to read, instead of worrying about such tiny, tiny micro-optimizations

Answer (score 2):

Answering the question itself, the two given snippets are compiled to identical bytecode, but not the same as concise version suggested by @rgettman and Óscar López.

```
private final Random r = ThreadLocalRandom.current();

private boolean test() {
    return r.nextBoolean();
}

boolean full() {
    if (test()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

boolean part() {
    if (test()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

boolean id() {
    return test();
}
```

Result:

```
        boolean full();
        Code:
        0: aload_0
        1: invokespecial #2                  // Method test:()Z
        4: ifeq          9
        7: iconst_1
        8: ireturn
        9: iconst_0
        10: ireturn

        boolean part();
        Code:
        0: aload_0
        1: invokespecial #2                  // Method test:()Z
        4: ifeq          9
        7: iconst_1
        8: ireturn
        9: iconst_0
        10: ireturn

        boolean id();
        Code:
        0: aload_0
        1: invokespecial #2                  // Method test:()Z
        4: ireturn
```

However, **all versions showed exactly the same performance on Hotspot JVM.**

Answer (score 0):

A good compiler would produce equivalent byte code.

In this instance you should be guided by readability (see other answers about removing the conditional altogether).